# How to get enum value from java interface with JNI C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, unreal-engine4

I have JAVA class that initialize AdMob SDK.

```
public void initialize(@NonNull Context context, RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration) {
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);

        MobileAds.initialize(context, initializationStatus -> {
            Map<String, AdapterStatus> statusMap = initializationStatus.getAdapterStatusMap();

            for (String adapterClass : statusMap.keySet()) {
                AdapterStatus status = statusMap.get(adapterClass);

                assert status != null;
                android.util.Log.d(AMManager.LOG_TAG, String.format(
                        "Adapter name: %s, State: %s, Description: %s, Latency: %d",
                        adapterClass, status.getInitializationState(), status.getDescription(), status.getLatency()));
            }

            OnInitializationResponse(statusMap);
        });
}
```

It calls native OnInitializationResponse method. With C++ realization:

```
JNI_METHOD void Java_com_somniumgame_admaster_admob_AMAdMobService_OnInitializationResponse(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jobject adapterStatus)
{
    TArray<FAdapterStatus> AdaptersStatus;
    FAdapterStatus AdapterStatus;

    if (JNIEnv* Env = AndroidJavaEnv::GetJavaEnv())
    {
        // Get the Map's entry Set.
        jobject EntrySet = AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallObjectJavaMethod(adapterStatus, "entrySet",
            "()Ljava/util/Set;");

        // Obtain an iterator over the Set
        jobject Iterator = AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallObjectJavaMethod(EntrySet, "iterator",
            "()Ljava/util/Iterator;");

        // Iterate over the entry Set
        while (AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallBoolJavaMethod(Iterator, "hasNext", "()Z")) {
            jobject Entry = AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallObjectJavaMethod(Iterator, "next",
                "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
            
            jobject Value = AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallObjectJavaMethod(Entry, "getValue",
                "()Ljava/lang/Object;");

            AdapterStatus.AdapterName = AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallStringJavaMethod(Entry, "getKey", 
                "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
            AdapterStatus.State = EAdAdapterState::AM_Ready;
            AdapterStatus.Latency = AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallIntegerJavaMethod(Value, "getLatency",
                "()I");
            AdapterStatus.Description = AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallStringJavaMethod(Value, "getDescription",
                "()Ljava/lang/String;");
            /*AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallObjectJavaMethod(Value, "getInitializationState",
                "()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/initialization/AdapterStatus$State");*/

            AdaptersStatus.Add(AdapterStatus);

            Env->DeleteLocalRef(Entry);
            Env->DeleteLocalRef(Value);
        }
        
        Env->DeleteLocalRef(EntrySet);
        Env->DeleteLocalRef(Iterator);

        AsyncTask(ENamedThreads::GameThread, [=]() {
            UAdMasterBPLibrary::OnInitializationCompleted.ExecuteIfBound(AdaptersStatus);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogAdMaster, Log, TEXT("Failed to get Java Env"));
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to get state.

```
AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallObjectJavaMethod(Value, "getInitializationState", "()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/initialization/AdapterStatus$State");
```

It crashed:

```
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/o1sxxx/o1s:12/SP1A.210812.016/G991BXXS5CVHI:user/release-keys'
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : Revision: '22'
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : Processor: '7'
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2022-10-11 15:33:30.839325252+0300
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : Process uptime: 5s
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : Cmdline: com.YourCompany.AdMobPlugin
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : pid: 2570, tid: 2570, name: any.AdMobPlugin  >>> com.YourCompany.AdMobPlugin <<<
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : uid: 10743
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/ads/zzbrt;.getInitializationState()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/initialization/AdapterStatus$State"
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : (Throwable with no stack trace)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :     in call to CallVoidMethodV
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :     from void com.somniumgame.admaster.admob.AMAdMobService.OnInitializationResponse(java.util.Map)'
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  00000a0a  r2  00000006  r3  ff8af6a0
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :     r4  ff8af6b4  r5  ff8af698  r6  00000a0a  r7  0000016b
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :     r8  ff8af6a0  r9  ff8af6b0  r10 ff8af6d0  r11 ff8af6c0
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :     ip  00000a0a  sp  ff8af670  lr  ead800d1  pc  ead800e4
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 000390e4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+172) (BuildId: b9fda42141bf3c824ab7a266107ef924)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 004ea5bb  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+602) (BuildId: 0083703d7cd34e09cb64d07a3011b856)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0000fcbf  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+46) (BuildId: 3981c30dc1982fe5c7463d7f0aea76c3)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 0000f57f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+230) (BuildId: 3981c30dc1982fe5c7463d7f0aea76c3)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 0022df47  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+2786) (BuildId: 0083703d7cd34e09cb64d07a3011b856)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 001f6de9  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+56) (BuildId: 0083703d7cd34e09cb64d07a3011b856)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 001ed0e5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...) (.__uniq.99033978352804627313491551960229047428)+40) (BuildId: 0083703d7cd34e09cb64d07a3011b856)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 001ecd09  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckThread(_JNIEnv*) (.__uniq.99033978352804627313491551960229047428)+348) (BuildId: 0083703d7cd34e09cb64d07a3011b856)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 002ff0e3  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType*) (.__uniq.99033978352804627313491551960229047428)+362) (BuildId: 0083703d7cd34e09cb64d07a3011b856)
10-11 15:33:31.735  3042  3042 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 001ef3ad  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CheckCallArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck&, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, art::InvokeType, art::(anonymous namespace)::VarArgs const*) (.__uniq.99033978352804627313491551960229047428)+184) (BuildId: 0083703d7cd34e09cb64d07a3011b856)
```

Realization of JNI wrapper:

```
jobject AdMasterAndroidUtils::CallObjectJavaMethod(jobject object, const ANSICHAR* MethodName, const ANSICHAR* MethodSignature, ...)
{
    if (JNIEnv* Env = AndroidJavaEnv::GetJavaEnv())
    {
        jclass Class = Env->GetObjectClass(object);

        jmethodID Method = FJavaWrapper::FindMethod(Env, Class, MethodName, MethodSignature, false);

        va_list Args;
        va_start(Args, MethodSignature);
        jobject Result = Env->CallObjectMethodV(object, Method, Args);
        va_end(Args);

        Env->DeleteLocalRef(Class);

        return Result;
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogAdMaster, Log, TEXT("Failed to get Java Env"));
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

AdapterStatus Realization:

```
package com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public interface AdapterStatus {
    int getLatency();

    @NonNull
    AdapterStatus.State getInitializationState();

    @NonNull
    String getDescription();

    public static enum State {
        @NonNull
        NOT_READY,
        @NonNull
        READY;

        static {
            AdapterStatus.State var0 = new AdapterStatus.State("NOT_READY", 0);
            NOT_READY = var0;
            var0 = new AdapterStatus.State("READY", 1);
            READY = var0;
            AdapterStatus.State[] var1 = new AdapterStatus.State[]{NOT_READY, READY};
        }

        private State() {
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how can I get int value of State? On C++ side I want to convert it to UE4 ENUM.

Comment: `JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:` check the results it's not found one of the methods. In fact the rest of the line says which method.

Comment: @RichardCritten yep, I understand this. But method AdapterStatus.State getInitializationState(); 
I added code snippet with AdapterStatus interface. How Can I call getInitializationState();?